# Formula for propagating errors in sd on difference of two random variables

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation

I have 2 series of vectors, each series describes means and their associated standard deviations like this:

```
means1 = c(2800.2, 5701.8, 8911.8, 11782.6, 16080.9, 19031.5)
sd1 = c(257.3, 274.1, 471.4, 228.6, 410.1, 750.0)

means2 = c(4.1, 2823.3, 5558.8, 8483.4, 11500.1, 14623.3)
sd2 = c(8.8, 38.1, 154.3, 77.6, 350.5, 441.7)
```

I need to generate a third series substracting means1-means2 (which is easy enough), but I couldn't find a way of propagating the errors. I know there's a formula you can plug, but I was wondering if there's a specific command in R that does this.

Comment: The standard deviation of the difference of two random variables will depend on their correlation. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115518/determining-variance-from-sum-of-two-random-correlated-variables.

Comment: This is a statistical question rather than a programming one; probably get a better quality of answer at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If your variables are uncorrelated (or if you don't have access to the primary data to find the covariance), the uncertainty is just the sum of the variances: ```sd3 = sqrt(sd1^2 + sd2^2)```

Comment: Thank you rsoren. I'll do just that. I was just wondering whether R had built-in a function to deal with error propagation.